# How do I update a specific cell in access

Tags: ms-access

I'm making a stock control database and I would like to know how I can update just one cell when a shipment is received. I have an 'orders' and a 
'stock' table, the idea is that the user would use a form to say that they have received a shipment, and the 'order amount' from 'orders' would be added to the amount in the 'stock' table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use Access SQL:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE stock SET amount=amount+" & me.amount & " WHERE itemID=" & me.itemID
```

But there are many different ways depending on what your exact situation is. The above assumes that you are in a form where you just filled in a new order and want to add the amount to the stock table.